# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType

Tags: python, function, recursion, factory

I am new user in Python, I have a problem with the None type, I looked different question, but the problem persists.

my code is calculate factorial

```
def fact(k): 
    if k > 0: 
        result = k + fact(k-1) 
        print(result) 
    else: 
        result=0 
    return result

fact(3)
```

Comment: Please show your code or an example.

Comment: The error indicates that one of the variables in a `x + y` expression is `None`.

Comment: def fact(k):
 if k > 0:
  result = k + fact(k-1)
  print(result)
 else:
  result=0
  return result
fact(3)

Comment: Based on the error code it sounds like you are trying to add an int and an empty variable "NoneType" and if you are doing a factorials it's likely an edge when you hit this in your loop, ie the very first iteration or very last.  Either use the debug feature of your IDE, or temperarily insert print(type(variable_name)) in your code and see when NoneType shows up  of course sharing your actual code helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and could not produce that error.  I think you have some indentation issues where your loop is not following the logic you are expecting.  Remember what is in the loop and what is out of the loop is dependent on the white space, so be careful with tabs and spaces.

Also there are some errors in your logic

1. you need k * fact(k-1) not +
2. the else should be result = 1

edited code is this:

```
def fact(k): 
    if k > 0: 
        result = k * fact(k-1) 
        print(result) 
    else: 
        result=1 
    return result
```

Also a more Pythonic way to write your function is to have it return the actual result instead of passing the result to a variable and returning the variable.
My assumption is that you're printing the result within the function to trouble shoot as this certainly in your final version would be removed.  Regardless, try this code instead:

```
def fact_v2(k): 
    if k > 0: 
        return k * fact_v2(k-1) 
    else: 
        return 1
```

and you would call you function like this:

```
print(fact_v2(11))
```

Good luck, Python is a fun language and may seem intimidating at fist, but you'll get there!

Comment: as a side note, if you don't want to actually print the function, the version 2 that I provided is nice as you can pass the result to a variable ie: eleven_factoral = fact_v2(11)